# Apply props default values based on inferred type

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props

How to apply different default values to components props when using union type-based declarations?

```js
<script setup lang="ts">

import { defineProps, withDefaults } from 'vue';

interface PropsA {
  name: 'a',
  option?: 'x' | 'y',
}

interface PropsB {
  name: 'b',
  option?: 'y' | 'z',
  otherOption?: boolean,
}

type ComponentProps = PropsA | PropsB;

const propsDefaultsA = {
  option: 'x',
};

const propsDefaultsB = {
  option: 'z',
  otherOption: true,
};

withDefaults(defineProps<ComponentProps>(), {
  ...propsDefaultsA,
  ...propsDefaultsB,
});

</script>
```

Above example returns following TypeScript error:

```
Argument of type '{ options: string; otherOption: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InferDefaults<Readonly<Omit<ComponentProps, never> & {}>>'.
  Types of property 'options' are incompatible.ts(2345)
const propsDefaultsA: {
    options: string;
}
```

This is not even a viable attempt since the default value for `options` from `propsDefaultA` is overridden by the `propsDefaultB`.

Answer (score -1):

the types for `propsDefaultsA` and `propsDefaultsB` are not inferred as `PropsA` and `PropsB` respectively, but you can cast them as such.

```js
withDefaults(defineProps<ComponentProps>(), {
  ...(propsDefaultsA as PropsA),
  ...(propsDefaultsB as PropsB)
})
```

Comment: The TypeSript error is now gone. Unfortunately, and as stated in the intial post, the attempt may not be the correct approach: the default values are applied without consideration of the inferred type `PropsA` and `PropsB`. Additionally, the default values from `propsDefaultA` are overridden by the `propsDefaultB`.

Comment: It not works. I have the error with InferDefaults<CurrentType>